# What does the Storable typeclass do in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have been reading some documentation on Haskell's C FFI. And I've just encountered a typeclass called `Storable`, which I don't understand very well.

Are instances of this typeclass, those types are supposed to have a "pointer" to them while interfacing with the C code?

Also what do the individual functions `sizeOf`, `alignment`, `peek`, `poke` do? It seems `peek` and `poke` are used to read data from or write data to a place in memory pointed to by `Ptr a`. Is this right?

But I don't know what `sizeOf` and `alignment` mean at all. Can someone give examples to clarify their use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Haskell stores values in memory in a way that is very incompatible to C. As a result, it is not possible to call a C function from haskell and pass to it haskell values directly. Instead, you have to create a copy of the value, but not an exact copy, but rather in a format that is understood by C. That's what `Storable` does. So it essentially provides way to serialize haskell values to a C friendly format (e.g. think C structs). It also supports the opposite operation, it can deserialize values. This is useful when a C function is called from haskell and returns a complex (i.e. non primitive) value.

The serialization/deserialization happens with the help of `poke`/`peek`. `sizeOf` returns the byte size of the C representation of the value. Note that this mechanism only works for values that have a C representation of fixed size (e.g. structs). It does not support things like C strings, they are treated [differently](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-C-String.html). As for `alignment`, it used to ensure that memory allocations done in the haskell land satisfy the platform's alignment requirements.

Comment: @smilingbuddha yes, I fixed it. In way, it doesn't make sense to talk about the size of the haskell representation of a value, because that representation is very opaque to the user. You have no way of inspecting how haskell stores its values.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the `alignment` function in some more depth? Suppose I have `data MyData = MyData { intarray :: [Int], dbarray::[Double],  length::Int}` How would I write an implementation for `alignment`?

Comment: For the alignment, you typically copy the alignment of C's `int` type. You can do that like so: `alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: CInt)`.

Comment: If you have that `MyData` type, then writing a `Storable` instance for it doesn't really make sense, since you can't represent values of that type in a fixed size.